How to change lubridate hms format to hours (with decimals) only
I have a column called Wait.Time which contains durations in the lubridate format of HMS
How do I convert this column to hour only? I.e. if one of my observations is 2H 30M 0S, how do I get that to become 2.5? This does not need to stay as the class format - it works well for it to change to numeric.

You can use the lubridate functions to parse period objects to convert the period into seconds then divide by 3600.
x  <- lubridate::hms("2h30m0s")
as.numeric(lubridate::seconds(x)) / (60 * 60)
# [1] 2.5

I have to say, though, I find these functions slightly confusing. You might expect as.numeric(lubridate::hours(x)) to produce 2.5 but in fact you get 32400000.
Alternatively, it may be more readable to write a helper function to parse the relevant parts of the time:
get_decimal_hours  <- function(x) {
    x$hour + (x$minute / 60) + (x$second / (60*60))
}

get_decimal_hours(lubridate::hms("2h30m0s")) #  2.5
get_decimal_hours(lubridate::hms("9h20m0s")) #  9.333333
get_decimal_hours(lubridate::hms("9h20m59s")) # 9.349722


You should check the type of Wait.Time with class() to be sure of the format.
It's probably POSIXct.  This solution should work for POSIXct.  Subtract a reference time (perhaps the min()) and coerce to numeric with as.numeric(x, units = "hours").
The possible values of units are shown in the docs for difftime: units = c("auto", "secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks")
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
  
x <- seq(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + hours(5), by = 300)

class(x)
#> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

(x - min(x)) |> 
  as.numeric(units = "secs")
#>  [1]     0   300   600   900  1200  1500  1800  2100  2400  2700  3000  3300
#> [13]  3600  3900  4200  4500  4800  5100  5400  5700  6000  6300  6600  6900
#> [25]  7200  7500  7800  8100  8400  8700  9000  9300  9600  9900 10200 10500
#> [37] 10800 11100 11400 11700 12000 12300 12600 12900 13200 13500 13800 14100
#> [49] 14400 14700 15000 15300 15600 15900 16200 16500 16800 17100 17400 17700
#> [61] 18000

(x - min(x)) |> 
  as.numeric(units = "hours")
#>  [1] 0.00000000 0.08333333 0.16666667 0.25000000 0.33333333 0.41666667
#>  [7] 0.50000000 0.58333333 0.66666667 0.75000000 0.83333333 0.91666667
#> [13] 1.00000000 1.08333333 1.16666667 1.25000000 1.33333333 1.41666667
#> [19] 1.50000000 1.58333333 1.66666667 1.75000000 1.83333333 1.91666667
#> [25] 2.00000000 2.08333333 2.16666667 2.25000000 2.33333333 2.41666667
#> [31] 2.50000000 2.58333333 2.66666667 2.75000000 2.83333333 2.91666667
#> [37] 3.00000000 3.08333333 3.16666667 3.25000000 3.33333333 3.41666667
#> [43] 3.50000000 3.58333333 3.66666667 3.75000000 3.83333333 3.91666667
#> [49] 4.00000000 4.08333333 4.16666667 4.25000000 4.33333333 4.41666667
#> [55] 4.50000000 4.58333333 4.66666667 4.75000000 4.83333333 4.91666667
#> [61] 5.00000000

Created on 2024-04-26 with reprex v2.1.0

I'm not sure this will work with Period objects from lubridate. If I do as.POSIXct(lubridate::hms("2h30m0s")) it produces "1970-01-01 01:00:00 BST"

hms::as_hms gives you a difftime object.
difftime is the rbase class for durations.
The lubridate alternatives are Duration ou Period.
From lubridate cheat sheet:

Durations track the passage of physical time, which deviates from clock time when irregularities occur.


Periods track changes in clock times,
which ignore time line irregularities.

About hms::as_hms:

An hms is a time stored as the number of seconds since 00:00:00

as_hms is a difftime class, hmssubclass.
> class(as_hms(now()))
[1] "hms"      "difftime"

you can see get numeric representation with base::is.numeric.
As a lubridate solution, with the considerations above, you can use as_duration or as_period:
> as.numeric(my_time)
[1] 32360.47
> as.duration(my_time) 
[1] "32360.4656729698s (~8.99 hours)"
> as.period(my_time)
[1] "8H 59M 20.4656729698181S"

So your choice depends on the type of math you want to do (changes in clock time vs. physical passage of time) and if you're interested in lubridate benefits (visualisation and convenience functions).
